# Python - Same letter but different font/ascii code/encoding?

Tags: python, string, encoding, ascii, data-processing

I am trying to make a simple algorithm that takes some text and predicts some probabilities. In the way of processing text as individual words, I realized that I have words/characters that have different ascii code even though their meaning for me/my algorithm should be the same. For example, I found this `'ａｒｅ'` and `'are'`. The first one seems to have a different font or something like that. If I get their hash code in Python is also different:

```
hash('ａｒｅ') #5179570038677318294
hash('are') #-5669913536749823475
```

If I check the individual ascii code:

```
ord('ａ') #65345
ord('a') #97
```

So, I was wondering if anybody knows why is this exactly and, of course, any work around. The ideal result I would like is to consider `'ａｒｅ'` and `'are'` as the same word so that I can group them. (The data is stored in a .csv file in a virtual machine)

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

In case this is useful, the best solution for me was:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
unidecode(text)
```

Since this could easily also remove accents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can normalize the string using `unicodedata.normalize`:

```
import unicodedata
ord(unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', 'ａ')) # 97
```